# Need XSLT to remove the tag when it has no value but attribute exists

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing

I have XSLT which is working fine in removing the tags if their value is empty/null.

But I am not able to remove the tags with following structure:

```
<cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="EUR"/>
```

inputXML:

```
<cbc:LineTotal currencyID="EUR">1989.65</cbc:LineTotal>
<cbc:LineAmount currencyID="EUR"/>
<cbc:dummy/>
```

Expected output:

```
<cbc:LineTotal currencyID="EUR">1989.65</cbc:LineTotal>
```

My current XSLT is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:if test="normalize-space(string(.)) != ''
                    or count(@*[normalize-space(string(.)) != '']) > 0
                    or count(descendant::*[normalize-space(string(.)) != '']) > 0
                    or count(descendant::*/@*[normalize-space(string(.)) != '']) > 0">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:if test="normalize-space(string(.)) != ''">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- remove elements with no content other than attributes -->
<xsl:template match="*[not(node())]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```